# Pass trough props only one property in typescript react

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a parent component and I need to pass trough props only the `product name` property into my "Title" component so then I don't have to loop the info inside my children component.

Here I have an image to explain my problem [image: Code image]

```
const DetailView = () => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState<Product[]>([])

  return (
    <>
      {products.length > 0 ? (
        <>
          <Title products={ need to access product image here  } />
          <Header products={products} />
          <Grid container>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={12} md={4} lg={4}>
              <ProductImage products={products} />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={12} md={8} lg={8}>
              <Results products={products} />
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
          <Grid container>
            <Chart />
          </Grid>
        </>
      ) : (
        'Loading...'
      )}
    </>
  )
}
```

And here is the type interface Product

```
export interface Product {
  _id: string
  _index: string
  _score: number
  _shop: {
    alias: string
  }
  _similarity_percentage: number
  _source: {
    g_shop_name: string
    product_match_token: string
    product_last_data: {
      product_id: string
      product_url: string
      product_created_at: string
      product_images_list: string[]
      product_name: string
      product_price_currency: string
      product_price_description: string
      product_price_value: number
      product_prices_list: any[]
      category_name: string
      product_brand_name: string
      g_shop_name: string
      _type: string
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't quite get what you're asking. What information are you trying to pass to the `Title` component, and what issue are you having with what you've attempted?

Comment: Are you trying to create a section for each product in your `products` array? If so, you want to use `map`.

Comment: Hi need to pass `product_name` into my `Title`component. Because I was looping the products into the title component but then they asked me to change so that it receives only the property it needs from the array of products

Comment: One product name, or an array of product names for all products? Right now only the second option (an array of product names) would make sense with how you have your component structured.

Comment: An array on product names

Comment: Understood. Daksh's answer is mostly correct, that would be my answer as well for the problem as I understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for!
first, change the `Title` component props type to this

```
interface ITitleProps {
    productsNames: string[],
}
```

then what you can do just simply extract the property from your products.

```
// using state
const [productsNames, setProductsNames] = useState<string[]>([]);
useEffect(() => {
   setProductsNames(products.map(p => 
   p._source.product_last_data.product_name));
}, [products])
// pass to Title component
<Title productsNames={productsNames}>

// OR using re-rendering of react
// in your return statement
<Title productsNames={products.map((p) => p._source.product_last_data.product_name)}/>
```

Hope this will resolve your problem.

Comment: fwiw I'd recommend the second pattern, just doing the mapping on each re-render, it's not expensive here. If you are worried about performance, `useMemo` makes more sense than `useEffect` in this case-- useEffect will eventually update the state, but `useMemo` does it immediately if the new render contains a new array of products.

Comment: `const productNames = useMemo(() => products.map(p => 
   p._source.product_last_data.product_name)), [products])`  (caches the result of the mapping whenever `products` changes)

Answer (score 2):

```
<Title products={products.map(p => p._source.product_last_data.product_name)} />
```

This will pass through an array of `string`s :)